# Non-degenerate solutions in multiplicative subgroups of $\mathbb{Q}$ of finite ranks

Tags: nt.number-theory, decidability

I am trying to study whether of a set of first order sentences is decidable, and the key is to figure out an algorithm to compute all non-degenerated solutions. The setting is as follow. Let $q = (q_{1},...,q_{n}) \in \mathbb{N}^{n}$ and for each $i$, $q_{i}>1$. Define the multiplicative subgroup $$q^{\mathbb{Z}} := \left\{\prod_{i=1}^{n}q_{i}^{n_{i}}:n_{i}\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$ For any linear equation $$a_{1}x_{1}+ \cdots + a_{k}x_{k} = 1$$ where $a_{i} \in \mathbb{Q}$, we say $b := (b_{1},...,b_{k}) \in (q^{\mathbb{Z}})^{k}$ is a non-degenerate solution if $\sum_{i \in I}a_{i}b_{i} \neq 0$ for any $I \subseteq \{1,...,k\}$. Several results have shown that for each linear equation with at least two variables, there exist finitely many non-degenerated solutions in $q^{\mathbb{Z}}$, so I can get all solutions by enumerating over $\mathbb{Z}^{k}$. Furthermore, there are results giving loose bounds on the number of solutions of a given linear equation and the rank of the multiplicative subgroup. However, the problem with loose bound is that I do not know if I have enumerated all possible solutions, so this method only works if I have a precise bound. I am wondering if in recent time, there are result directly giving a precise bound in this special case, or there are results that ensure all non-degenerated solutions are in a finite subset of $q^{\mathbb{Z}}$. For example, if all solutions are in a closed ball center at $0$ in $\mathbb{Q}$, then I can have a bound on the maximal Euclidean norm of all non-degenerated solutions.

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: It is confusing to have rational $a$ and $b$ but integer $q$.